# Ruby on Rails: How to get monthly count by using PG

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

Now I'm facing a issue that is I want to write a statement to return monthly count,

For example, in period of 2014-01 to 2014-12. return an order array like

```
["Jan, 5", "Feb, 0",...,"Dec, 55" ]
```

The possible solution that I only know is

```
1. get a scope to return monthly record
2. calculate the period number, like here is 12 
3. repeat 12.times to get record size for each month
4. build array
```

The problem is I have to repeat queries for 12 times! That's so weird.
I know group_by could be a better choice, but no idea how to achieve the performance which I really want to be. Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Format your date column using [Postgres's to_char](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-formatting.html) and then use it in ActiveRecord's group method.

```
start = Date.new(2014, 1, 1)
finish = Date.new(2014, 12, 31)

range = start..finish

return_hash = ModelClass.
              where(created_at: range).
              group("to_char(created_at, 'Mon YYYY')").
              count
```

That will return a hash like `{"Nov 2014" => 500}`

To 'fill in the gaps' you can create a `month_names` array and do:

```
month_names.each{ |month| return_hash[month] ||= 0 }
```

Consider creating a new hash altogether that has keys sorted according to your `month_names` variable.

Then to get your desired output:

```
return_hash.map{ |month, count| "#{month}, #{count}" }
```

Comment: if there is no any record in a month, like,['Jun', 55, 'July, 0', 'Aug, 50']. I don't know how to insert 0 to array while monthly records are 0.

Answer (score 0):

I use the groupdate gem (https://github.com/ankane/groupdate)

Then add `.group_by_month(:created_at).count` to your query